# Error with two MultiUploader in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I want to create 2 `MultiUploader` elements to upload `jpg` and `pdf` separately in my `Composite` class in `GWT`

```
public class MyClass extends Composite{
...
    @UiField(provided = true)
    MultiUploader muplDefPdf;
    @UiField(provided = true)
    MultiUploader muplDefJpg;
...
    private void setMuplDef(MultiUploader muplDef, String extention,
            IUploader.OnFinishUploaderHandler onFinishUploaderHandler,
            IUploader.OnCancelUploaderHandler onCancelUploaderHander) {
        muplDef = new MultiUploader();
        muplDef.setServletPath(muplDef.getServletPath());
        muplDef.setValidExtensions(extention);
        muplDef.setMaximumFiles(5);
        muplDef.avoidRepeatFiles(true);
        muplDef.addOnFinishUploadHandler(onFinishUploaderHandler);
        muplDef.addOnCancelUploadHandler(onCancelUploaderHander);
    }

    public MyClass() {
        setMuplDef(muplDefPdf, "pdf", onFinishUploaderHandlerPdf,
                onCancelUploaderHanderPdf);
        setMuplDef(muplDefJpg, "jpg", onFinishUploaderHandlerJpg,
                onCancelUploaderHanderJpg);
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

    private IUploader.OnFinishUploaderHandler onFinishUploaderHandlerJpg = new IUploader.OnFinishUploaderHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onFinish(IUploader uploader) {
           ...
        }
    };
    private IUploader.OnCancelUploaderHandler onCancelUploaderHanderJpg = new IUploader.OnCancelUploaderHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(IUploader uploader) {
          ...
        }
    };

    private IUploader.OnFinishUploaderHandler onFinishUploaderHandlerPdf = new IUploader.OnFinishUploaderHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onFinish(IUploader uploader) {
           ...
        }
    };
    private IUploader.OnCancelUploaderHandler onCancelUploaderHanderPdf = new IUploader.OnCancelUploaderHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(IUploader uploader) {
           ...
        }
    };
...
}
```

My problem is that I get an error

```
 Exception caught: UiField muplDefJpg with 'provided = true' was null
```

Why I have this error when I define `muplDefJpg` before `initWidget`.
How to resolve my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is not related to GWT *per se*, but with Java itself. When you do:

```
private void setMuplDef(MultiUploader muplDef, ...) {
    muplDef = new MultiUploader();
```

... you must remember that in Java you always copy the reference of the parameter when you call a method (more about that in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)). In that matter, you can't pass your `muplDefPdf` field as parameter expecting it to be instantiated inside the method.

For your code to work properly, you need to do:

```
public MyClass() {
    muplDefPdf = new MultiUploader();
    setMuplDef(muplDefPdf, "pdf", onFinishUploaderHandlerPdf,
            onCancelUploaderHanderPdf);
    muplDefJpg = new MultiUploader();
    setMuplDef(muplDefJpg, "jpg", onFinishUploaderHandlerJpg,
            onCancelUploaderHanderJpg);
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
}
```

... and remove the `muplDef = new MultiUploader();` line inside the `setMuplDef` method.